# Fill data from column X to Column Y if Y has NaN using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, nan

I have a column say X with some data. I want to move this data into another Column say Y. I got the code to do it.

[This shows column X and Y # in Column Y meaning NAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REXLT.png)
The code is as below:

```
id = df['X'].str.extract(r"(\d[8]s\d[2])",expand=False).tolist() #extracting values which look like 12345678s12 and i include NaN values 

df_new= pd.DataFrame({'Y':id})
wb = load_workbook('text.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']
for index, row in df_new.iterrows():
    cell = 'Y%d'  % (index + 2)
    ws[cell] = row[0]
wb.save('text.xlsx')
```

The problem I'm facing is there is some data in Column Y and code overwrites the whole column Y with id.
I don't want this to happen.I want to retain the data in column Y and only if there are NaN values in it, I want those to be replaced by the corresponding value of id.

Comment: Do you want to replace values from `x` to `y` where `y` contains `#`?

Comment: Yes thats what is my expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html)

You can mask one series with another:

```
df['Y'].mask(df['Y'] == '#', df['X'], inplace=True)
```

Here's a demo with the version which does not work in place:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
                   'Y': ['#', '1', '2', '#', '3']})

df['Y'] = df['Y'].mask(df['Y'] == '#', df['X'])

print(df)

   X  Y
0  A  A
1  B  1
2  C  2
3  D  D
4  E  3
```

Comment: Incase if there was a blank in place of # how would the code change ?

Comment: If by blank you mean empty string, use `df['Y'].isin(['#', ''])` for your Boolean condition. If you mean null value (`NaN`), use `df['Y'].isnull() | df['Y'].eq('#')`.

Comment: thanks.. but how do i transfer it back to the excel file and in place of df['X'] can i use id so that i can just give the extracted data.

Comment: @AdarshBhansali, You are asking at least 3 questions there. If you have another question, please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
df['Y'] = np.where(df['Y']=='#', df['X'], df['Y'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.where`

```
df['Y'] = np.where(df['Y'] == '#', df['X'], df['Y'])
```

Answer (score 0):

#### [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Do you want to replace values from `x` to `y` where `y` contains `#`

If So try this,

```
df.loc[df['Y']=='#','Y']=df['X']
```

As your objective is only want to replace records where `Y` has `#`, So **mask or lock the index where Y has #** then assign values from `X` to `Y` to only locked index.

If you want to deal with blank then,

```
df.loc[df['Y'].isnull(),'Y']=df['X']
```